# Flutter Error : The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm having unknown exception thrown when I run the app on emulator :

```
The _ScaffoldLayout custom multichild layout delegate forgot to lay out the following child:
```

I'm using `Flutter 1.0.0` and `Dart 2.1.0`

I tried to look up on google but couldn't find the solution.

Here is my code :

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Text Input Example"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Flexible(
              child: TextField(
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16.0
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Remove Flexible from your code and it should work

Comment: Can you show the code of initState()

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Got the same error while trying to hot-reload or hot-restart my app.
Cold restarting it (stop then start again) fixed it.

Comment: The issue can happen when changing a widget from stateless to stateful or the other way around and trying reloading after. Restarting the app seems to solve the issue.

Comment: This still happens if an app is released in debug.